# Brightness of image on canvas Iphone 13 pro

Tags: javascript, html, ios, iphone, webrtc

I'm trying to get image from phone camera to canvas to save it later.

My problem is when i use iPhone 13 Pro then the image on canvas is brighter than it should be.
This happens only when i draw image on iPhone 13 Pro, other ios and android phones do not have this problem.

This is how i pass video stream to canvas

```
  let video = document.createElement('video');
  let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  let ctx = container.getContext('2d');

  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    audio: false,
    video: {
      width: 1920,
      height: 1020,
      facingMode: 'environment'
    }}).then(stream => {
      window.stream = stream;
      video.srcObject = stream;
      const track = stream.getVideoTracks()[0];

      video.setAttribute('playsinline', 'true');

      video.play();

      requestAnimationFrame(() => {
       
        ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      });
  })
```

[The image in `<video>` element stays at normal brightness (iPhone 13 pro)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESc8T.jpg)

[Image from iphone 13 pro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrOMH.jpg)

[Image from android phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVyzO.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was problem with `width: 1920, height: 1020,` params in getUserMedia. I deleted it and it works fine now.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).